# Do we have $A/(q-1)A \cong \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb{C}(q)$ be the field of rational functions in $q$. Let $A$ be a local subring of $\mathbb{C}(q)$. Do we have $A/(q-1)A \cong \mathbb{C}$? Thank you very much.

Edit: we assume that $A$ is the local ring of $\mathbb{C}(q)$ consisting of all rational functions which are regular at $q=1$.

Comment: Could you be more precise? Many subrings of $\mathbb{C}(q)$ (e.g. the local ring $\mathbb{Q}[q^4, q^6]_{(q^4, q^6)}$) don't even contain $q-1$ as an element, so $A/(q-1)A$ wouldn't even make sense!

Comment: @Hurkyl, thank you very much. Now I assume that $A$ contains all rational functions in $\mathbb{C}(q)$ which are regular at $q=1$.

Comment: Thus, $A=\Bbb C[q]_{(q-1)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your edit, it's true : the isomorphism comes (by passage to the quotient) from the surjective morphism $A\to \Bbb C$ defined by evaluating an element of $A$ at $1$ whose kernel is precisely $(q-1)A$ (check it !).